# Styles in defined Window.Resources for a Catel Window do not apply to children of Window

Tags: wpf, mvvm, catel, wpf-style

MainWindow.xaml

```
    <catel:Window x:Class="Experimetns.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:catel="http://schemas.catelproject.com"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
        <catel:Window.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </catel:Window.Resources>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBox Height="30px" Width="100" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"></TextBox>
        </Grid>

    </catel:Window>
```

The `ForeColor` setting above does not apply to the `TextBox` whereas the below works

```
    <catel:Window x:Class="Experimetns.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:catel="http://schemas.catelproject.com"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
        <catel:Window.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </catel:Window.Resources>
        <Grid>

            <Grid.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"></Setter>
                </Style>
            </Grid.Resources>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBox Height="30px" Width="100" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"></TextBox>
        </Grid>

    </catel:Window>
```

Does anyone have an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by the window styles being injected into the generated window grid that Catel creates (see http://docs.catelproject.com/vnext/catel-mvvm/views/xaml/advanced/usercontrol-under-the-hood/ for a detailed explanation).

You can either define them on the app-level or inside the root content of the window. You could also look into [Orchestra](https://github.com/wildgums/orchestra) to help you with the resource dictionaries etc.

Comment: Using Orchestra already, what feature would I use? Also, is this not considered a bug if the injected grid does not replicate the resources?

Comment: Then the reason could be Orchestra injecting the styles into the data window. Just define them on a lower level and all should be fine.